# PSpice NMOSFET switch voltage

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, simulation, buck, pspice

[image: PSpice Circuit]

I'm working on a more complex design, but noticed there's something strange going on so decided to test this simple circuit that turned out to behave unexpectedly.

For some reason the voltage on R1 never goes even close to 5V (below 0.2 V) when the switch is being closed. Does anybody know what is the cause of that?

Comment: Where did you measure your output? Can you tell us how you simulated the circuit (i.e. your parameters, what analysis you ran, etc.)? Also, what is your threshold voltage?

Comment: I measured the top of the resistor (tried both sides actually, the other one is steady ground). I run it just for about 20 cycles of switching (~50ms). I set the threshold voltage to 2V, and the simulation confirms that the 'CLK' alias is switching between 0 and 3V. Edit: Also tried grounding the pulse source at the source of the NMOS - similarly low voltage on the resistor.

Comment: Try a PMOS device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have built seems to be a so-called "Source Follower". In order for the NMOS transistor to conduct, it needs a certain gate-source voltage to conduct current: \$v_{GS}>V_{th}\$.

So let's say the NMOS transistor is switched "on", then the voltage over the resistor will start to increase. This causes \$v_{GS}\$ to decrease, and the NMOS transistor will - eventually - switch itself back off if \$v_{GS}\$ gets too small.

In order for the NMOS transistor to keep conducting, it needs a certain \$v_{GS}\$ drop to provide the resistor with the current it wants.

The maximum output voltage you could reach due to the above is \$V_{gate} - V_{th}\$, and this only happens for really, really big output resistors. In your comments you stated you have a \$V_{th} = 2V\$, and your clock signal when on is \$V_{gate} = 3V\$. The *maximum* output voltage will therefore be around \$1V\$.

If you decrease the resistance, the NMOS transistor needs a higher \$v_{GS}\$ in order to conduct the necessary current (at \$V_{GS}=V_{th}\$ it conducts almost no current). This extra "overhead" voltage in your case is then likely around \$0.8V\$.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. In the meantime, I started tinkering around a circuit where the low side of the VPULSE is connected to the source terminal, to make sure the VPULSE is affecting Vgs directly. It started to work when I pulled the VPULSE high to 3.5 V, which for me makes no sense. My guess is that PSpice's NMOS might have other properties that I have not set, set to default and that's why the GS voltage needs to be higher than the threshold itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have the source and drain reversed.  Switch source and drain and when V = +5 the switch will be off.  When zero, it will be on.

Comment: Won't the body diode conduct?

Comment: You have a P-channel MOSFET in your schematic.  The body diode is in the opposite direction from an N-channel.

Comment: Not my schematic, but the arrow points inward. It's an NMOS. As drawn the body diode is reverse biased (cathode toward +5V). If you swap S and D the diode will be forward biased. It *should* be a PMOS to function as a high-side switch.

Comment: My error.  On the post it appeared to be a p-channel.